# EC2 Unable to install composer "Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/ec2-user/.composer"

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I have a Linux AMI EC2 server that I'm trying to install composer on. Usually the process is pretty simple but in this case I just can't get it to work.

```
$ cd /home/ec2-user/
$ rm composer-setup.php 
$ php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
$ php composer-setup.php
All settings correct for using Composer
Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /home/ec2-user/.composer
```

I tried `chmod 777 /home/ec2-user` and then `php composer-setup.php` but I get the same error.

I tried this too:

```
$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
All settings correct for using Composer
Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /root/.composer
```

I also tried going into my project directory on the server and doing the following:

```
$ sudo su
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
All settings correct for using Composer
Unable to write keys.dev.pub to: /root/.composer
```

I confirmed that the `.composer` directory does not exist in my users's home directory

```
$ ls -la ~ | grep composer
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 305459 Feb 27 17:27 composer-setup.php
```

I'm really stomped here. Would really appreciate any hints or suggestions.

Comment: What does 'ls .composer' tell you? That's the directory it's trying to write to (not 'composer')

Comment: @TheFiddlerWins $ ls ~/.composer
ls: cannot access /home/ec2-user/.composer: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

After a very long time, I figured out that composer installation was failing because the `file_put_contents` function was disabled on my server. Unfortunately when the install failed, it didn't indicate what was causing the problem and did not write anything into my PHP error log (I confirmed that PHP error logging was set up & working correctly). After re-enabling the `file_put_contents` method, the install worked like a charm. I just wish it gave me more details upon failing. If anyone knows a way to get additional failure details during installation, please let me know.